# modificar un fichero que se encuentra dentro de un jar

Tags: java

Alguien podría decirme como puedo modificar ficheros de texto que se encuentran
en un jar, todo desde código java. Lo he intentado de todo pero nada funciona.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. ¿Podrías ser mas específico respecto a tu problema? ¿Con que razón quieres modificar los archivos dentro de un jar? ¿Que es "todo" lo que has intentado?

Comment: Utilizo ficheros de configuracion properties dentro de un paquete properties de mi proyecto, pero cuando lo ejecuto desde netbeans funciona correctamente pero al ejecutarlo desde el jar es lo que no puedo modificar el properties que se encuentra dentro

Comment: Hola Francisco. Esto suena al [problema XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), donde en vez de explicar el problema real que necesitas resolver, te estás centrando en lo que tu piensas que es la solución. En realidad, es muy poco probable que necesites modificar el jar. Si explicas la razón detrás de la pregunta (y con detalles), probablemente se te puede sugerir una mejor solución.

Answer (score 2):

Debido a que un archivo .jar es considerado un archivo comprimido similar a un .zip, usted puede usar el paquete `zip` que provee Java:

> Proporciona clases para leer y escribir los formatos de archivo estándar ZIP y GZIP.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html

> El presente ejemplo contiene dos métodos:

- Escribir (Introduce dentro del archivo `fichero.jar` el archivo `archivo.txt`)
- Leer (Lee el nombre de los archivos dentro de `fichero.jar`)

  ```
  public class Clase {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

      Escribir();
      Leer();

  }

  public static void Escribir() throws IOException {
      ZipOutputStream os = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("fichero.jar"));

      os.setLevel(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
      os.setMethod(Deflater.DEFLATED);

      ZipEntry entrada = new ZipEntry("archivo.txt");
      os.putNextEntry(entrada);

      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("archivo.txt");
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int leido = 0;
      while (0 < (leido = fis.read(buffer))) {
          os.write(buffer, 0, leido);
      }

      fis.close();
      os.closeEntry();

      os.close();
  }

  public static void Leer() throws IOException {

      @SuppressWarnings("resource")
      ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("fichero.jar"));

      ZipEntry entrada;
      while (null != (entrada = zis.getNextEntry())) {
          System.out.println(entrada.getName());

          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(entrada.getName());
          int leido;
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          while (0 < (leido = zis.read(buffer))) {
              fos.write(buffer, 0, leido);
          }
          fos.close();
          zis.closeEntry();
      }

  }
  ```

  }

> Con la presente clase, usted puede ser capaz de Leer y modificar los archivos .txt que necesite. Siéntase libre de realizar los ajustes que considere pertinentes.

[image: Muestra de la jerarquía de los archivos en IDE Eclipse]

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por reponder pero solo tengo una pregunta mas, ¿Con ese codigo podria modificar solo el archivo properties que se encuentra dentro de un paquete dentro del jar sin afectar a los demas paquetes del jar que contienen las clases?.

Comment: Sí, ¡por supuesto! Sólo es necesario que agregues la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo "properties". Ejemplo: directorio/directorio2/properties

Comment: Ya, muchas gracias, lo voy a intentar y luego envio el resultado

Comment: Excelente, si la respuesta resolvió la duda no olvides marcarla como respuesta. Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Lo siento mucho, pero lamentablemente no me funciona nuevamente, ya lo intente de todo pero no hay remedio, me dice que no encuentra el directorio

Comment: Para que se entienda mejor, estoy trabajando con netbeans y estoy desarrollando un proyecto que utiliza archivos properties de configuracion en una carpeta llamada properties que esta incluida en el mismo proyecto y mi objetivo es aprender a como reescribir en el fichero properties pero con el proyecto ya compilado, osea desde el jar

Comment: Entiendo, ¿estas iniciando el aprendizaje del lenguaje Java cierto? Para poder dar más detalles, es necesario que compartas el código que tienes, para que sea más fácil. De otro modo se tiene que replicar el caso y no siempre coincide. Pues las rutas deben tratarse con cuidado, en sistemas Mac, Windows y Linux. Pero por supuesto existen formas de hacer genérico el PATH. (File.separator).

Comment: En primer lugar llevo 1 año programando en java, te envio como queda el codigo, pero de todas formas no me funciona

Comment: No me funciona el codigo, el sistema que uso es windows 7

Comment: Esto te puede servir http://aandresdev.blogspot.pe/2017/01/modificar-un-archivo-dentro-de-un-jar.html

Comment: No logro observar el código fuente.